# Use lambdas to create new Object from 2 existing Objects, summing up various values from various Objects in ArrayList fields

Tags: java, lambda

I have this bean, MyBean. MyBean contains a couple of Lists of ComplexObjects, that in turn each have Lists of SimpleObjects, which has a simple int field (field1).

What I would like to do is take 2 MyBean Objects -- which will be exactly the same except for the values in the SimpleObject.field1 fields --
and use lambdas / mapTo / reduce / whatever, and sum up each int field (field1), and create a new MyBean with the new sums, but maintaning the rest of the fields (the Lists) as is.

My Objects look like this:

```
public class MyBean {
  private ArrayList<ComplexObject1> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
  private ArrayList<ComplexObject2> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class ComplexObject1 {
  private ArrayList<SimpleObject1> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class ComplexObject2 {
  private ArrayList<SimpleObject1> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class SimpleObject1 {
  private int field1;
}

public class SimpleObject2 {
  private int field1;
}
```

I have little experience with lambdas, but I'm hoping I can use them here. I'm just not sure how. I know how to use lambdas sum up values in fields of various Objects, but I don't know how to create a new Object with these sums, since they live in sub-sub-Objects.

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Will be hard to do with only private fields ... On a more serious note, what you want will only work if lists of the same type have the same size.

Comment: The Lists will all be the same size. That will be exactly the same except for the 'field1' values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data model is basically the same as a `List<List<Integer>>`. So, if I understand correctly, you want to make a new list like that with the elements of the inner lists of two other lists summed.

Test data:

```
// [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7]]
List<List<Integer>> list1 = 
  new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(1,2,3), Arrays.asList(4,5,6,7)));
// [[10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60, 70]]
List<List<Integer>> list2 = 
  new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(Arrays.asList(10,20,30), Arrays.asList(40,50,60,70)));
```

New list will be `list3`:

```
List<List<Integer>> list3 = new ArrayList<>();

List<Integer> tmp = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++){
    for (int j = 0; j < list1.get(i).size(); j++){
        tmp.add(list1.get(i).get(j) + list2.get(i).get(j));
    }
    list3.add(new ArrayList<>(tmp));
    tmp.clear();
}
```

Which now contains `[[11, 22, 33], [44, 55, 66, 77]]`.

I'll leave it for you to rewrite this to your situation with the `List<ComplexObject>` and `List<SimpleObject>`.

---

Unreadable 'streamy' solution:

```
list3 = new ArrayList<>(
Stream.of(list1, list2)
  .flatMap(x -> IntStream.range(0,x.size()).mapToObj(index -> new SimpleEntry<>(index, x.get(index))))
  .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.toMap(   SimpleEntry::getKey, 
                                SimpleEntry::getValue, 
                                (a, b) -> {return IntStream.range(0, a.size())
                                                    .mapToObj(index -> a.get(index) + b.get(index))
                                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());})
          , Map::values)));
```

This produces the same result as the first solution.

Comment: Yes, thanks, that's what I want to do, but I was hoping to be able to do it with Lambdas. If I can't figure it out, I will do it pretty much as you explained it. But in the interest of having more concise code, and getting my head around Lambdas, I'd like to try using reduce or something similar.

Comment: Doing this with Streams should be possible and may be more concise. However, the code will likely be a lot harder to read.

Comment: Just added a possible solution using Java 8 Streams. I am sure it can be improved/shortened/optimized, but the readability ....

Comment: Well it certainly is unreadable! Im going to have to study it, but in the meantime I chose it as the solution

Comment: ... that is some serious lambda guru stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stream` and `flatMap` methods to iterate through list and calculate the `sum` e.g.:

```
int sum = list1.stream()
          .flatMap(co -> co.list1.stream())
          .mapToInt(so -> so.field1)
          .sum();
```

This way, you will be able to calculate the `sum` of all the sub elements for a list.

Comment: Right, this is what I want to do, to get the sums, but I would also like the output to be a new MyBean with everything the same except the values in each 'field1' where I would have the sum of the values in 'field1' for the 2 MyBean Objects.

Comment: @RobertBowen once you get the sum, you can `stream` through the list again and set the value in `forEach` function. Let me know if you need an example.